# pie() got an unexpected keyword argument 'startangle'

Tags: python, matplotlib

As the title already indicates I am getting a `TypeError` when calling the following method:

```
plt.pie(ylist, labels=xlist, autopct='%1.1f%%', startangle=90, counterclock=False)
>>> TypeError: pie() got an unexpected keyword argument 'startangle'
```

When I leave out `startangle` I get a `TypeError` for `counterclock`:

```
plt.pie(ylist, labels=xlist, autopct='%1.1f%%', counterclock=False)
>>> TypeError: pie() got an unexpected keyword argument 'counterclock'
```

When I also leave out `counterclock` it works fine and I get the desired plot.

However according to the [documentation](http://matplotlib.org/api/pyplot_api.html#matplotlib.pyplot.pie) those two keywords actually exist and I also checked the version of my **python-matplotlib** library to be up-to-date (it's not possible that the module *matplotlib.pyplot* is out-dated while *matplotlib* is up-to-date, is it?). By the way, I am using Python 2.7.3.

Can someone explain this error?

Comment: What version is it, specifically?

Comment: Using `dpkg -s python-matplotlib | grep 'Version'` I get the output `Version: 1.1.1~rc1+git20120423-0ubuntu1`.

Comment: 1.1.1 is not even close to up-to-date. The latest version as of now is [1.4.0](http://matplotlib.org/contents.html).

Comment: I installed the library a couple of days ago using `apt-get install python-matplotlib` and just tried `apt-get install --only-upgrade python-matplotlib` without any success. How can I update it then?

Comment: I assume you have done `apt-get update` recently?

Comment: Right before I tried to upgrade. However my Ubuntu tells me that there is a "New Ubuntu release '14.04.1 LTS' available". Could it be necessary to upgrade Ubuntu?

Comment: You can start with [the docs](http://matplotlib.org/users/installing.html) then. Ask a new question if you have problems you are unable to solve.  **Edit:** Yes, the newer distribution may have separate repositories with more recent packages. But you can always install software by other means than `apt`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Indeed matplotlib version 1.1.x [didn't have that](https://github.com/matplotlib/matplotlib/blob/v1.1.x/lib/matplotlib/pyplot.py#L2442):

```
def pie(x, explode=None, labels=None, colors=None, autopct=None,
        pctdistance=0.6, shadow=False, labeldistance=1.1, hold=None):
```

while version 1.4.0 [does](https://github.com/matplotlib/matplotlib/blob/master/lib/matplotlib/pyplot.py#L3060):

```
def pie(x, explode=None, labels=None, colors=None, autopct=None,
        pctdistance=0.6, shadow=False, labeldistance=1.1, startangle=None,
        radius=None, counterclock=True, wedgeprops=None, textprops=None,
        hold=None)
```

Answer (score 2):

I had the same problem this morning after moving to a new install, Ubuntu 12.0.4

What worked in the end was:

```
$pip uninstall matplotlib  
$apt-get remove --purge python-matplotlib  
$wget https://github.com/matplotlib/matplotlib/archive/master.zip
```

Unzip, cd to new directory matplotlib-master,

```
$python setup.py build   
$python setup.py install
```

then check with pip:

```
$pip show matplotlib
Name: matplotlib
Version: 1.4.0
Location: /usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages
Requires: numpy, six, python-dateutil, pyparsing, nose, mock, nose, mock
```

## Success!